# Library, which helps packing structures with good performance

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures

Days ago I heard (maybe I've even seen it!) about library, that helps with packing structures. Unfortunately - I can't recall it's name.

In my program I have to keep large amount of data, therefore I need to pack them and avoid loosing bits on gaps. For example: I have to keep many numbers from range 1...5. If I would keep them in char - it would take 8bits, but this number can be kept on 3 bits. Moreover - if I would keep this numbers in packs of 8bits with maximum number 256 I could pack there 51 numbers (instead of 1 or 2!).

Is there any librarary, which helps this actions, or do I have do this on my own?

Comment: I think you're looking for bit fields.

Comment: Do you need to maintain order?  If not then have a look at a Radix-tree/Crit-bit tree.  Where the key would be the number(1...5) and the value would be the count of occurrences of said number. 

This is one method for how network routers keep track of so many IP addresses.

Comment: ASN.1 or google protobuf maybe? Depending on your needs, maybe zlib.

Comment: How large is a large amount of data? How much speed are you willing to spend in reducing the memory size of the application?

Comment: There are about 10^8 records, every at least 4B. I will have to keep it twice (from different perspectives). I would like to have linear access to every data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tomalak Garet'kal already mentioned, this is a feature of ANSI C, called bit-fields. The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields) is quite useful. Typically you declare them as structs.

For your example: as you mentioned you have one number in the range of 0..5 you can use 3 bits on this number, which leaves you 5 bits of use:

```
struct s
{
    unsigned int mynumber : 3;
    unsigned int myother : 5;
}
```

These can now be accesses simply like this:

```
struct s myinstance;
myinstance.mynumber = 3;
myinstance.myother = 1;
```

Be awared that bit fields are *slower* than usual struct members/variables, since the runtime has to perform bit-shifting/masking to allow access to simple bits.